# Broblem for wallet blockchain privet key

Tags: private-key

When I want to convert btc from my wallet blockchain, they ask me to enter my private-key. When I enter it, I am asked to enter the password for the private-key. I do not know the password for private-key.

Is there a solution?

Answer (score 1):

Without more information, I see a few posibilities:

1. You may have a BIP38 encrypted private key.

see: https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0038.mediawiki

I suspect that maybe you are trying to claim a paper wallet?  If so, you need to know the password, or brute force it (unlikely).

2. If you are referring to a blockchain.com (formerly blockchain.info) wallet, those are proprietary to them and use their own format for the keys.  Again, you need to know the password, or brute force it.

If you don't have the password to your key any longer, then there are some wallet recovery services on the internet, which are risky and take a large percentage of the balance.  You can google "bitcoin wallet recovery", and always check reviews before engaging with one of these services to check their reputation.  Even so, they may be unable to recover the password.

Barring that desperation, do not provide your private key to anyone!

Answer (score 0):

yes, depending on how much knowledge and effort you want to spend. But it is cumbersome, and requires a deep learning curve. Normally the private key should have 51 chars starting with "5", or 52 chars starting with "K" or "L". In rare cases you might have a hex value private key, that is a 32 characters long string. (Never post your private key here!!!).

Also you need to verify, if you have a "xpriv key" - that is a slightly different way of presenting a priv key, and has additional usage. This plays a role, when reloading into another wallet.

I am not familiar with blockchain.info, and if the private key is somehow encrypted with this password - maybe some research required. If it is encrypted, then this is not of much help, and I can't do anything for you.

So if you have one of those priv keys beginning with "5" or "K" or "L", then you have options:
You might get a wallet (like Electrum), and load the priv key there. It would then show you the corresponding address, and you can verify, if it is correct. It would then also show the funds. 
Also you can assemble a transaction manually, sign it manually, and get it relayed to the bitcoin network. But this requires a good amount of sophisticated knowledge of the bitcoin network (at the command line layer).